# Can't view my table, getting an error "mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource"

Tags: php, mysql, html-table, forum

I am trying to display a view topics table that displays forum in a table, 
however I am getting an error that says:

> "mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1  to be resource"

I cannot seem to find what I am missing in my code. I have replaced short tags `<?` for `<?php` but this has not helped. Help please!

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="test"; // Mysql username 
$password="test"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="test"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="forum_question"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// get value of id that sent from address bar 
$id=$_GET['id'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>

<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<td><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bordercolor="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><strong><?php echo $rows['topic']; ?></strong></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><?php echo $rows['detail']; ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><strong>By :</strong> <?php echo $rows['name']; ?> 
<strong>Email : </strong><?php echo $rows['email'];?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><strong>Date/time : </strong> <?php echo $rows['datetime']; ?></td>
</tr>
</table></td>
</tr>
</table>
<BR>

<?php

$tbl_name2="forum_answer"; // Switch to table "forum_answer"
$sql2="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name2 WHERE question_id='$id'";
$result2=mysql_query($sql2);
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
?>

<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<td><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><strong>ID</strong></td>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1">:</td>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><?php echo $rows['a_id']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="18%" bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><strong>Name</strong></td>
<td width="5%" bgcolor="#F8F7F1">:</td>
<td width="77%" bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><?php echo $rows['a_name']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><strong>Email</strong></td>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1">:</td>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><?php echo $rows['a_email']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><strong>Answer</strong></td>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1">:</td>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><?php echo $rows['a_answer']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><strong>Date/Time</strong></td>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1">:</td>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><?php echo $rows['a_datetime']; ?></td>
</tr>
</table></td>
</tr>
</table><br>

<?php
}

$sql3="SELECT view FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$id'";
$result3=mysql_query($sql3);
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result3);
$view=$rows['view'];

// if have no counter value set counter = 1
if(empty($view)){
$view=1;
$sql4="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(view) VALUES('$view') WHERE id='$id'";
$result4=mysql_query($sql4);
}

// count more value
$addview=$view+1;
$sql5="update $tbl_name set view='$addview' WHERE id='$id'";
$result5=mysql_query($sql5);
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Is the id in the table a string or an integer?

Comment: which line of code error occured..?

Comment: this is the line of error >>$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);

Comment: Could you post some schema? Also, beware of [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Before iterating your `$result` array, print like `print_r($result)` or `mysql_num_rows($result)`and check what you got ?

Comment: guys... the query failed ;) therefore, result2 is not a resource

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the line

```
$result2=mysql_query($sql2);
```

with

```
$result2=mysql_query($sql2) or die("MySQL Error: ".mysql_error());
```

(**EDIT:** and the same for `$result`)

because if the result of the query is not a resource it means that the query did not succeed.

Comment: mysql_fetch_array returns array with both integer and column-based keys www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array

Comment: I found out that the problem was with 'id' its trying to get 'id' from the address bar. however its not showing up the id in the address bar but when I enter id=1 it shows up. this is the code i have in my main forum

`code`          <?php echo $rows['id']; ?></td>
          <a href="view_topic.php?id=<? echo $rows['id']; ?>"><?php echo $rows['topic']; ?></a><BR></td>